# is there any way to check if an email sent landed in a spam folder?

Tags: email, spam, bulk-email

In email marketing it's useful to provide a statistic about messages that got across as spam to the people that want to send an email campaign.

From what I know so far, it isn't possible to check if an email sent landed in a spam folder. Is there anything that I'm missing? Even something that will work a small percent of the time will do.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: When you ask about spam folders it sounds like you're talking about spam detection at the level of the user's email program. Are you also interested in checking if an email was detected as spam by their email gateway (e.g. their ISP has spam detection too)?

Comment: @paulmorriss yes, I'm interested in detection at any level; is the message supplied by the ISP in case it has spam detection a standard one? are there a lot of ISPs with spam detection?

Answer (score 1):

If the email gateway rejects it as spam it may return it with SMTP code 571. For Google's Postini email service this means it thinks it's spam: http://www.google.com/support/appsecurity/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=134416

However 571 can be used for other reasons, like the email gateway thinks the incoming message has a virus.